# Restrict the Image byte array conversion to PNG format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've a Web API which takes images (it can be jpeg or png) from a folder and convert it to byte array and send to the calling application.

I use the below function to convert the images to binary:

```
public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
{
    FileStream fS = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] b = new byte[fS.Length];
    fS.Read(b, 0, (int)fS.Length);
    fS.Close();
    return b;
}
```

And below 'data' will be passed to the Web API response.

```
byte[] data = ImageToBinary(<PATH HERE>);
```

What I want is to restrict this 'data' to be converted to PNG format only in the application from where this Web API is called.

Purpose is that I don't want every time to remind the other developer who is coding the other application that you need to convert it to PNG only.

Answer (score 0):

A PNG allways start with `0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A` bytes.

So, you can check the first bytes of file and the extension.

On an API you should comment your code and use good method names to prevent errors. You can change your method name from `ImageToBinary` to `PngImageToBinary`...

```
public static readonly byte[] PngSignature = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A };
/// <summary>
/// Convert a PNG from file path to byte array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imagePath">A relative or absolute path for the png file that need to be convert to byte array.</param>
/// <returns>A byte array representation on the png file.</returns>
public static byte[] PngImageToBinary(string imagePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(imagePath)) // Check file exist
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", imagePath);
    if (Path.GetExtension(imagePath)?.ToLower() != ".png") // Check file extension
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(imagePath, "Requiere a png extension");
    // Read stream
    byte[] b;
    using (var fS = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        b = new byte[fS.Length];
        fS.Read(b, 0, (int)fS.Length);
        fS.Close();
    }
    // Check first bytes of file, a png start with "PngSignature" bytes
    if (b == null
        || b.Length < PngSignature.Length
        || PngSignature.Where((t, i) => b[i] != t).Any())
        throw new IOException($"{imagePath} is corrupted");

    return b;
}
```

Comment: ImageToBinary function is used in the Web API to generate the byte[] which will send to the other application, so I was looking for a method where I can make sure that when the byte[] is received in the other application it cannot be converted to any other format but PNG only.